# PHP not reflecting desired HTML

Tags: php, html, css

I'm making a website where a user should be able to use HTML and CSS in their profiles but I came across one problem.

```
    <?php
    $profile = "<h1>THIS IS A TEST</h1>";
    echo htmlentities($profile);
    ?>
```

That's my code, but it only show this in the profile:
`<h1>THIS IS A TEST&amp</h1>`

I don't know what is happening, nor do I know if this only happens to me.

How do I make it show only the h1 content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use `echo $profile;`, that's all. Check [this](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) and don't forget to check *Display as HTML* as browsers display PHP echoed text as HTML unless they're told to display it differently.

Comment: Thanks, i did never thinked abaout trying this myself :)

Answer (score 2):

Function `htmlentities` is showing the representation of html characters like tags etc., and is being used especially to avoid parsing as html. So if you mean to echo html so that the browser parses it as html, the last thing you want is to use this function! Just echo it out directly, no need to use `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars`!